# Generating Word Document in Aspnet Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, docx, xceed

I am migrating an application from asp.net MVC to Aspnet Core v2.1. 
I have the following code to generate a Word Document and when I hover over the document I can see the properties such as Paragraphs, Images, Footer etc all set; but when I save I always get a 5Kb document with no content. It should return the document as a stream to download by the browser, but I have also included an explicit .SaveAs("C:\blah") which produces same file.

```
var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
DocX document = DocX.Create(fileStream, DocumentTypes.Document);
Paragraph p1 = document.InsertParagraph();
p1.Append("Hello world");


document.SaveAs(fileStream);
fileStream.Position = 0;
fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

 document.SaveAs("C:\\Code\\MyFile.docx");

var fsr = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
fsr.FileDownloadName = "MyFile.docx";

return fsr;
```

I don't get any errors either in the application or in my Event Viewer.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the DocX library by Xceed is not yet supporting .Net Core. [DocX is not supported in .net core applications.](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/issues/31)

You can try using [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) instead.